Stamp serial / bates number while printing
I want to print 50 copies of the same 16-page document but have a serial number stamped on each one. I'm printing to a Ricoh/Lanier multifunction printer. Right now I print and staple through lpr with a line like:
lpr -P <printer> -# 50 -o StapleLocation=UpperLeft file.pdf

So I was hoping a combination of other options could accomplish this.
I've researched and found various options to watermark the same text on each document, like "DRAFT" or "CONFIDENTIAL". But I'd like each copy to have a different number watermarked or stamped on top.
I can write a program using PyPDF to create several files, each starting from a source file and stamping custom text over it. But printing 50 16-page files takes a lot longer than printing one file 50 times. Any advice is appreciated.

Do you want to print the serial number on every page of the document?  Or just, say, the title page?

I'd be happy either way

In an ideal world, you should be able to write a tiny bit of PostScript
that is executed by the interpreter in the printer to do this, as all the
concepts exist in the language to enable this.
The PostScript operator currentsystemparams can retrieve information from
the printer that can include PageCount, an integer that is: "The number
of pages that have been successfully processed since manufacture".
That could be used as a unique serial number, that the PostScript code
could add to the page output.
Alternatively, the code can "make persistent alterations to objects in
VM" by using the startjob operator, which needs the printer administrator
password. A small non-printing job can be sent to the printer to initialise
a global counter with this technique. This is then accessible to later
jobs to retrieve, use, and update.
Both of these techniques probably won't work though, when setting a number
of copies, as the PostScript will be executed once only to rasterize each
page, and then identical pages will be printed for each copy.
Quotes are from an old PostScript language reference pdf.

Some printers to have watermark printing options, which you can enable as a driver option without having to generate a new document (i.e., the rasterizer in the printer only adds the additional watermark atop of the page), but that doesn't seem what you want here.
So, no matter what we do here (intense hacking around with cups filters and PPDs, or document generation), your printer will have to rasterize 800 pages; can't really be helped. So, your PyPDF approach sounds fine to me.
(I used LaTeX with the pdfpages package's \includepdf, something like
\newcounter{serialnr}{10000}%
\includepdf[pagecommand={\thispagestyle{empty}\arabic{serialnr}]{pdffile.pdf}%
\stepcounter{serialnr}%
\includepdf[pagecommand={\thispagestyle{empty}\arabic{serialnr}]{pdffile.pdf}%

(\pgffor makes this easier)

Thanks for the advice. There's also the old-fashioned solution

@MatthewLeingang if you're not paying per printed page, you can also first print the 50 copies, then feed them in again, the second time just printing empty pages aside from the serial nr. Let's call it a high-tech rubber stamp.

If you’re content to print the serial number on only the title page,

Split your document into p01.pdf and p02-16.pdf.
Print 50 copies of p02-16.pdf.
Write a program to make 50 variants of p01.pdf
with different serial numbers, and print them.
Manually shuffle.

If the manual shuffling is too time-consuming,
a variation is to write a looping script:
do 50 times:
begin
        make a copy of p01.pdf with a unique serial number, and print it
        print p02-16.pdf
end

That might not be any faster than your “printing 50 16-page files” solution.
Of course, if you’re printing double-sided,
you will need to split your document into p01-02.pdf and p03-16.pdf.

Thanks for this suggestion. The tradeoff is the manual stapling, of course, which is pretty valuable to me.
